# Zabbix cross-host dependency in graph during upgrade

Tags: zabbix, graph

We are planning to switch from currently installed zabbix 2.0.1 to latest version.

There is custom graph which aggregates few metrics from hosts in one group. Graph created and associated with one of these hosts. 
Problem is that this graph also becomes shared between all hosts from which metrics are added to graph. This problem occurs upon export/import phase of upgrade of zabbix and expressed in cross-host metric dependencies.

Is there any zabbix-idiomatic way to create such graph which will be free from dependency problem? Or there is only way in which we should delete graph in old installation, upgrade and then create it again?

Comment: Since Zabbix 2.2.0, database upgrade is automatic (see [What's new in 2.2.0](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/introduction/whatsnew220#automatic_database_upgrade) and [Upgrade notes for 2.2.0](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/installation/upgrade_notes_220#new_upgrade_procedure)). So you should make a backup of your database and just launch the new Zabbix binary. No export/import phase should be required. Could you please describe why this is not an option for you?

Comment: There is an issue in our installation which leads to problems with user privileges (misconfiguration or bug), so we decided to try data export and import between different versions of zabbix in prefer of direct upgrade.

Comment: If we have a trigger consisting of multiple items, then the trigger is listed on all hosts to which its items belong. The same situation is with graphs - a graph is shown on all hosts to which its items belong. I have tried exporting all of the graph's hosts together from 2.0 and import the resulting XML into 2.2. It works perfectly. Could you please describe why this export and import sequence is not an option for you, or why it fails?

Comment: I will try to collect that information, but it will be next Monday.
Also, I suggest workaround for problem, mentioned in my post, to our system administrator by implementing synthetic metrics from host metrics, collect them in virtual host and create graph for it. We will try it next Monday too.